# How do I just save last few seconds of a captured video (AVCaptureSession)

Tags: ios, video, video-capture, video-processing, avcapturesession

I want the user the record a continuos video at 240 FPS using iPhone 6. When the user presses a button, it should just save the last 10 seconds on file system for a later viewing pleasure.

How do I achieve this? I haven't found any good answer to this task.

I'm toying around with `AVCaptureSession` and `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` which automatically writes the stream onto the disk.

1. One approach is to not use `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` and build a ring buffer in memory and on button press, just save those 10 seconds onto the disk. Achievable using `NSData`?
2. Second approach I can think of is just use `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` as is, but on button press, just keep the last 10 seconds and cut off the rest to save space.

Currently I don't have any clue how I can do any of those 2 approaches. Can someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: Have you found a way to do that ? I'm looking exactly for the same task to add into my app.

Comment: sry, unfortunately not yet :(